# Select specific columns from First() row with Linq2sql

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I want to use `First()` in a **Linq2sql** query, but I don't want the database to return the whole row, just specific columns. Is there a way to do that?

If I use `Where()` I can then `Select()` (while it stays an `IQueryable`), but if I use `Where()` it will iterate over all rows instead of stopping when it finds a match.

Comment: `SELECT ColumnName FROM Table`?

Comment: @Sami I just now edited the question in case someone doesn't notice the `linq-to-sql` tag.

Comment: Do you want a linq answer or an SQL answer?

Comment: @jarlh According to the edit and the comment, he look for a linq answer

Comment: Write `Where().Select()` first and *then* use `First()`. That's the equivalent of `SELECT TOP 1 col1,col2 ..... WHERE ..`

Comment: Post your code. `Where()` won't iterate over all rows unless you *force* it to, by using functions that don't map to SQL. Only `Where()` will generate a `WHERE` clause that will limit the number of results.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You can post your comment as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: SELECT(new{col1, col2,....ColN}).First()

Comment: @DenisRubashkin So you're saying like Panagiotis, right? I assume this means you agree with him that this will indeed translate into a query that will _not_ iterate and then take the first, but rather stop at the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you use "Where" it does not iterate over all record until you actually execute the query. because thats how [linq works](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/charlie/2007/12/10/linq-and-deferred-execution/), until you actually use the result of the query (convert it to a list, bind to a gridview, etc...) it is not executed so you can add as many conditions as you want and they will combine into a single query.

so where.select.first should work